# Can a private Cardano network be created?

Tags: cardano

In Ethereum we can use geth to create a private network, for example by defining a genesis block with puppeth and then creating nodes.

Is there an equivalent of geth in Cardano and can we create private networks?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know much about Ethereum but to set up private network for cardano you need "Cardano-sl". Do set it up on your local or VPS according to this instruction https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/develop/docs/how-to/build-cardano-sl-and-daedalus-from-source-code.md . After downloading and building binaries from either nix or stack mode you need to connect your node to mainnet or testnet as per your requirement follow this link for the same: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/develop/docs/how-to/connect-to-cluster.md .

Now your node should start downloading blocks and it will take some time to complete sync. you can check synchronization progress by using simple curl command: curl -X GET https://localhost:8090/api/v1/node-info: also you need to provide certs with the request or can call with insecure option by proving -k option with the request, see API reference for complete info: https://cardanodocs.com/technical/wallet/api/v1/#

And once your node will be in sync, you can call APIs and create your wallet, accounts and do ADA transactions.

Although, I skipped some steps but i hope still it will help many to get going.

Comment: But no smart contracts?

Comment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125174/cardano